# How to fix invalid line break error in PUG

Tags: pug

I have the pug template -  layout pug

[layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rjkaD.png)

I want to extend this template with  some changes in block content
When I am extending layout in child template everything work great.

[child template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o9xDR.png)

But when I tried to rewrite any layout block, I see the invalid line break error in terminal

[pug error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wULL8.png)

Please help me with your advise to fix this problem. THX

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the extension of the file :

`extends common/layout.pug` as you can see in documentation [here](https://pugjs.org/language/inheritance.html).